# How to change/get the font(-size) in the "Console Application" using Windows API or internal command without changing the registry directly?

Tags: c, winapi, mingw32

I have searched in the MSDN, but nothing meet my needs.

Could anyone help me? THANKS.

```
#include <windows.h>
int main (void)
{
    // HOW TO ?
}
```

Comment: Did you really search? Google gave me back a nice [SetCurrentConsoleFontEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686200(v=vs.85).aspx)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get info on the console's font use:

- [`GetConsoleFontSize()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683165%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [`GetCurrentConsoleFont()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683176%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`GetCurrentConsoleFontEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683177%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

To set font info use:

- [`SetCurrentConsoleFontEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)